# How can I give permanent admin access to the Linux program such as Aptik?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I’m using Linux Mint x64 with KDE and I can run the app [Aptik](https://launchpad.net/apt-toolkit) fine from the terminal as sudo Aptik followed by its parameters. No problem. But I want to be able to run it from its GUI. The program launches fine.

But when I select any backup directory from the dropdown, the program closes. I think I found the problem but don’t know enough about Linux to fix it. When I access root/usr/bin and double-click on the file aptik-gtk, a window comes up that says:

> Aptik needs admin access to backup and restore packages. Please run
>   the application as admin ('gksu aptik-gtk').

Clicking “Ok” closes that window. When I go into terminal and do that, I get the following:

```
karl@karl-Inspiron-1545:/usr/bin > gksu aptik-gtk [14:28:58] App config loaded: '/root/.config/aptik.json'

(aptik-gtk:4454): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_tree_model_filter_get_value: assertion 'GTK_TREE_MODEL_FILTER (model)->priv->stamp == iter->stamp' failed

(aptik-gtk:4454): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.40.2/./gobject/gtype.c:4210: type id '0' is invalid

(aptik-gtk:4454): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: can't peek value table for type '<invalid>' which is not currently referenced 
karl@karl-Inspiron-1545:/usr/bin >
```

Now, as user `karl`, I want to give Aptik permanent admin access to any directories on my system to do my backups. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe setuid could help.

> setuid means set user ID upon execution. If setuid bit turned on a
>   file, user executing that executable file gets the permissions of the
>   individual or group that owns the file.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-bsd-linux-setuid-file/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my problem by deciding to give myself root access to my system as the only user. I'm aware of any security risks. I then got an error message at bootup about needing permission 644 on /home/.dmrc or something like that and solved that problem by following this thread (which explains it all)... https://help.ubuntu.com/community/dmrcErrors

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Linux Mint 17.1 KDE (32bit) and have the same problem as "user2712929". But, if you go to your console terminal prompt and type in "sudo aptik-gtk", enter your password, then the Aptik GUI interface will come up allowing you to backup.